# Macbook Pro Retina – "Battery Is Not Charging"

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, macos

My Retina MacBook Pro is currently on 4% battery power, but when I plug it in, the battery icon up the top shows the plug icon instead of the lightning bolt icon inside it to say it's charging and stays on the same 4%. How can I fix this so that my laptop charges fully?

*Screenshot:*

[image: MacBook Pro: 4% Power – Battery is Not Charging (Power Source: Power Adapter)]

Comment: Have you tried different outlets? Another charger? Option / Alt + Clicked the battery icon for more info?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I've tried different outlets to no avail, the battery condition is normal and I only have one charger so I'm unable to try any different ones

Comment: If it's not the outlet (I was thinking low voltage, so better if you try another building altogether) it may be the charger or the battery. If the battery says condition normal, I would think its the charger. Maybe go to an Apple Store and kindly ask to try the charger of one of the Macs on display?

Comment: It shows you are connected to the power adapter, means that is working. The battery not charging could be a result of a problem with SMC. Do a SMC reset for your model.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I reset my SMC and have just come back to my laptop after leaving it for quite a while. It still shows the plug icon however its charged up to 53% (yay) so I think it is just the quality of my charger is deteriorating and I need to purchase a new one. Thanks again :)

Comment: You did an SMC reset and it began charging…and your first thought is a charger problem?

Comment: The quality of your charger is unlikely to be an issue. It will either work normally or not at all. The quality of the battery is much more likely to be an issue, if the SMC reset hasn't fully sorted you out.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me too. I clean the connectors, especially the area around the pins on the computer case. This is a very small area; last time I used a heavy paper stock card and cleaned out any dust or debris that might have been there. Problem solved!  This has happened to my computer a few times and the solution is always getting either the power connector pins clean, or the metal areas immediately adjacent cleaned. It could be a grounding issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me after disconnecting my MacBook Pro Retina (late 2013) and then exhausting the battery on a Netflix marathon.

I left my MacBook unplugged for several days and then it began charging again.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the charger is not giving as much energy as is required for your computer not to lose charge when working normally. If you use the computer lightly, or you suspend it, or shut it down, you will get a slow recharge.

The cause for the low charge can be either a dirty Magsafe/USB-C socket, a faulty power supply, a misconfigured System Management Controller (SMC) —as indicated elsewhere—, or a self-resetting fuse in the power supply.

In this last case, removing the power supply from the wall socket and waiting a couple of minutes can resolve it.

If the issue is the SMC, you can follow the method indicated by Apple in their support document about ["How to reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

And if the issue is a dirty socket, you can try to use a compressed air can, or something like that, to blow away the dirt.

Answer (score 0):

I have had charging problems with my early 2013 (13 inch) MacBook Pro with retina display.  I replaced several charging adapters and have had the charging port on the computer replaced.  All replacements and the repair were more or less temporary.  I believe the problem is that the computer requires high current to charge, particularly when the battery is at a low charge level.  The current appears to be passing through only two pins of the five pins on at the magnetic connection.  Once the pins heat up, they tarnish and then are not able to conduct current well, causing them to heat even more.  The problem eventually will prevent current from passing through the connection and stop the computer from charging.  I just had the power adaptor replace and before using it, I vigorously rubbed a white pencil eraser over the pins (which are actually dimples) on the computer power socket.  I will continue to inspect the pins on both the adaptor and the computer and clean them as needed with a white pencil eraser.
I think the connection is a design flaw, particularly with the retina displays, which needs more charging current than the standard displays. Apple has changed their charger connections on the newer MacBook Pros, but they don't admit that there is a problem with the Mag Safe connection.

Comment: Hello and welcome!  You have posted your question as an answer... If you have a question please post it as a question... take a look at the site tour to get a sense of how the site works best https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour